# Sankey diagram in R networkD3 (or D3) end to end highlighting

Tags: r, d3.js, networkd3

I would like to build a sankey diagram that highlights a path from end to end. I would like to use something free and that doesn't require me to upload data to do so.

This Tableau visualization has exactly the functionality I want- when you hover over one link you can see the entire trajectory from start to finish without highlighting any other link that intersects with the same nodes and each of the link segments align cleanly:
https://public.tableau.com/profile/actinvision#!/vizhome/SuperstoreInteractiveSankeyShowcase/Sankey

I have been looking into the networkD3 package in R; the example at Christopher Gandrud’s github site even uses data in a format that I understand.

But how do I change the highlighting functionality?

And how do I make sure that the highlighted path isn't broken?  Once the whole path is highlighted I am hoping to also avoid having misaligned links (which would look something like this: http://qinming.github.io/d3-sankey-with-highlighting/ )

Thank you.

Comment: So you want the highlighting from the very first node to the last as in the the second link?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "when you hover over one link you can see the entire trajectory from start to finish".  In the example you mention [here](https://christophergandrud.github.io/networkD3/#sankey), the data is not structured like that.  For instance, "Nuclear" links to "Thermal generation" which links to "Losses", "Electricity Grid" and "District heating".  Nuclear has no path that goes from "start" to "finish"...

Comment: For instance, in the networkD3 example https://christophergandrud.github.io/networkD3/#sankey

Comment: In the networkD3 example  [link](https://christophergandrud.github.io/networkD3/#sankey) right now if I mouse over the link between Nuclear & Thermal Generation only that link highlights (Nuclear->Thermal 840Twh). What I'd like is if I hover over that same link I would highlight a whole path (Nuclear->thermal generation->losses); I want to convey the total amount of energy that follows this particular path. As @Mark commented, this data is formatted in a stepwise way; is there a way to reformat the data that would make NetworkD3 understand what I want? Thanks.